# Confused in getWindowHandle() method in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written two java file to understand how getWindowHandle() method works but i was confused by seeing two different output in two java file

**File 1 : WindowHandling.java**

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/SeleniumCode/Chapter%203/HTML/Window.html");
    String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    //System.out.println("First window handle is "+window1);
    
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Search"));
    link.click();
    Set<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String s:windowIterator)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**O/P :**

> {c1310e40-aaed-44cf-9581-61f3b84753fa}
>
> {7a99b954-3198-467f-9b49-9bb02e85d5b1}

**File 2:WindowHandler.java**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/SeleniumCode/Chapter%203/HTML/Window.html");
    String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("First Window Handle is: "+window1);
    WebDriver popup = null;
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Search"));
    link.click();
    String window2 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Second window handle is "+window2);
    driver.switchTo().window(window1);
    driver.switchTo().window(window2);
```

**O/P :**

> First Window Handle is: {478bdad7-e057-4d27-99ec-38db1f020f6d}
>
> Second window handle is {478bdad7-e057-4d27-99ec-38db1f020f6d}

How in first java code two window handle is different and in second java code it is same

Answer (score 0):

`link.click()` not changes the windows handler. In the first example you enumerated the handlers that driver has (`getWindowHandles` method). You may go between these handlers using switchTo method.  In the second example you receive the handler that uniquely identifies it within this driver instance (`getWindowHandle` method). Therefore you twice receive the same handler. And you print the handler before `switchTo` call.

Comment: Still i am confused what you replied

Comment: In the first example you enumerate all windows handlers that driver has - two. In the second example you always receive the only one handler that driver associated with.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you use:

```
Set<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles();  // plural!
```

and then you print out their handles in a loop.

In your second example the order of your (only relevant) commands is:

```
String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("First Window Handle is: "+window1);
// some irrelevant code here
String window2 = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Second window handle is "+window2);
// more irrelevant code:
driver.switchTo().window(window1);
driver.switchTo().window(window2);
```

Your problem is that the code is doing what you told it to do, not what you *think* you told it to do.